# Using jQuery UI datepicker in shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-component

I've created a vanilla web component. I have a `<input type="text" id="date">` in my Template file. I created the shadowDom and linked it to `this.root`. After I clone the template and attached it to `this.root`, I do the following:

```
$(this.root.querySelector('#date')).datepicker();
```

This instantiates the date picker but when I try using it, the datepicker is shown but it gives an error:

> Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker

Comment: It doesn't seems possible to use JQueryUI datepicker inside a Shadow DOM

Comment: @Supersharp found a way using `content`/`slot` HTML tags to reflect datepicker from light dom in the shadow DOM.

Comment: yes it's a good workaround however in this case the datepicker is not in the shadow dom

Comment: @Supersharp Is it still true that you cannot use the datepicker inside the shadow dom?

Comment: @J.Doe yes. i'm using pickaday instead: https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday

Comment: @Supersharp When testing the displayed date is spawned in the light dom. Is this intended?